# Head Unit with Android Bluetooth work around

Tags: android, bluetooth, root

I bough a PX6 Head Unit with Android 9.
I flashed a custom ROM, the Hal9k precisely.
Usually, these HU are BT limited to dialog only with smartphones and OBD devices.
Other devices not even are showed in the available BT list.

The problem is that I have a strip led bluetooth device, with it's own app, and would be nice to control it from the HU screen.
My smartphone recognize it and can control it without problem.

Well, since this ROM is rooted, there is a way to force to discover some device?
It's possible to implement the driver somewhere to make it work?

I'm not so expert so I just ask you.
I tried to contact HU developers and they told me it's not possible...

Answer (score 0):

I also have the Bluetooth LED strip problem.

I reached out to Dasaita and they said that even their latest (PX6-based) head units do not support Bluetooth connections other than to a phone or a an OBD2 device. This, in my view is very limited and I urged them to improve their bluetooth capabilities to be more versatile.

I tried adding a bluetooth dongle via USB but that did not work.

This answers your question, although it's not a very favourable one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we have no way to control other BT devices with Dasaita.
They say it's due to the chinese's law, but I don't think so.
With my previous chinese Atoto HU, I could control any BT device.
From keyboard to strip led...